# Register all Controllers programatic in Castle Windsor container from all assemblys

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I use this code...

```
        container.Register(
            AllTypes
            .FromAssembly(Assembly.Load("MyNamespace.Dashboard"))
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .Configure(component => component.LifeStyle.Transient
            .Named(ControllerNameFromType(component.Implementation)))
            );
```

... to register my controllers in the container but I would like to be able to register all controllers from all assemblys to get things more pluggable. I thought that the code below should work but it doesent?

```
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

        foreach (var assembly in assemblies) {
            container.Register(
                AllTypes
                .FromAssembly(assembly)
                .BasedOn<IController>()
                .Configure(component => component.LifeStyle.Transient
                .Named(ControllerNameFromType(component.Implementation)))
                );
        }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? if so, please post the full stack trace

Comment: Yes I get this exception http://pastebin.com/m3c41b842

Comment: That's a Linq2Sql exception, doesn't seem to be related to Windsor...

Comment: Ok but when i change the way I register my controller by specifying the assembly it all works great. I don't know if I have made some stupid thing with my container though, maybe it should't be static? http://pastebin.com/m6a363d02

Comment: it's ok as static... is your WindsorControllerFactory the standard one or does it have any modifications?

Comment: I have done some modifications to the controllerfactory and it looks like this http://pastebin.com/m8f17255

Comment: Exactly. in GetControllerType(string controllerName) engine.Repository.Load() can't find runtime type for type mapping 'Stormbreaker.Dashboard.Models.SysRoot'. That's what the exception is saying.

Comment: Is it necessary to say .Named(ControllerNameFromType(component.Implementation))) I thought that was what it did anyways?

Comment: I don't really know actually, I tried to inherit from WindsorControllerFactory instead and just overriding the GetControllerType method and it seems to work ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Check assemblies to see if all assemblies are loaded.

Do something like this if not:

```
        foreach (string dllPath in Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.dll"))
        {
            try
            {
                Assembly a = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(dllPath);
                if (Matches(a.FullName) && !loadedAssemblyNames.Contains(a.FullName))
                {
                    App.Load(a.FullName);
                }
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```